# How to remove a sublist which starts with particular element in python 3?

Tags: python

How to remove a sublist which starts with particular element in python 3?

```
updated_code_result_2_2 =[["DR JOHN","HOSPITAL"],["TOTAL CHARGES","5OO"],["yes"]]

def remove_dr(updated_code_result_2_2):
    rem_list = []
    rem_ele_list = ['DR','TOTAL']
    for x in updated_code_result_2_2:
        for i in rem_ele_list:
            if not x[0].startswith(i):
                rem_list.append(x)
    print(rem_list)
    return rem_list

remove_dr(updated_code_result_2_2)
```

Expected Output:
[["yes"]]

Comment: I see that you already have good answers to help you out.  Just thought I'd point out, in case it isn't obvious by the answers, that your solution doesn't work because you iterate over all the prefixes and append onto the new list if ANY of the prefixes don't match.  Of course, that's always going to be true.  You need to modify your code to only append to the new list if ALL of the prefixes don't match.  @bharatk's answer does this quite directly.  @Rakesh does this in a craftier way by making use of the fact that `startswith` can be called just once with your entire prefix list....

Comment: Both of the supplied answers are, IMO, good ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just change your existing code, use `temp` variable and if condition, if condition to check where the start element is matched.
Add break condition inside inner `for-loop` and set and temp variable is true.

```
updated_code_result_2_2 =[["DR JOHN","HOSPITAL"],["TOTAL CHARGES","5OO"],["yes"]]

def remove_dr(updated_code_result_2_2):
    rem_list = []
    rem_ele_list = ['DR','TOTAL']

    for x in updated_code_result_2_2:
        temp = False
        for i in rem_ele_list:
            if x[0].startswith(i):
                temp  = True
                break

        if temp is False:
            rem_list.append(x)

    print(rem_list)
    return rem_list

remove_dr(updated_code_result_2_2)
```

O/P:

```
[['yes']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty close. You can use a tuple inside `str.startswith`

**EX:**

```
updated_code_result_2_2 =[["DR JOHN","HOSPITAL"],["TOTAL CHARGES","5OO"],["yes"]]
def remove_dr(updated_code_result_2_2):
    rem_list = []
    rem_ele_list = ('DR','TOTAL')
    for x in updated_code_result_2_2:            #Iterate each element
        if not x[0].startswith(rem_ele_list):    #Check if element startswith anything from rem_ele_list 
            rem_list.append(x)
    return rem_list

print(remove_dr(updated_code_result_2_2))
```

Comment: Just curious - is it really true that you can only pass multiple prefixes to `startswith` as a tuple?  It doesn't work if you pass a list or some other sequence type? - If that's true, I'd be curious as to why.

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer a few optimizations to the existing solutions.  First, I'll point out that @bharatk's answer can be cleaned up by making use of the Python `for` loop's `else` clause:

```
updated_code_result_2_2 =[["DR JOHN","HOSPITAL"],["TOTAL CHARGES","5OO"],["yes"]]

def remove_dr(updated_code_result_2_2):
    rem_list = []
    rem_ele_list = ['DR','TOTAL']

    for x in updated_code_result_2_2:
        for i in rem_ele_list:
            if x[0].startswith(i):
                break
        else:
            rem_list.append(x)

    print(rem_list)
    return rem_list

remove_dr(updated_code_result_2_2)
```

Second, I'll point out that @Rakesh's solution can be done in a single line using a list comprehension:

```
updated_code_result_2_2 =[["DR JOHN","HOSPITAL"],["TOTAL CHARGES","5OO"],["yes"]]

def remove_dr(updated_code_result_2_2):
    rem_list = [x for x in updated_code_result_2_2 if not x[0].startswith(('DR', 'TOTAL'))]
    print(rem_list)
    return rem_list

remove_dr(updated_code_result_2_2)
```

Both of these also result in:

```
[['yes']]
```